# Access facebook html code in R

Tags: facebook, r

I'm not very familiar with APIs, ssl certs, etc. but I would like to access the underlying html code for facebook pages.  I'm having trouble using getURL() with Facebook, and "ssl.verifypeer = F" doesn't work.  Here's an example:

```
library(RCurl)
txt<-getURL("https://www.facebook.com/nytimes/", ssl.verifypeer = FALSE)
```

This only returns and empty string:

> txt = ""

Does this mean I need to use the Graph API?  Can you access underlying HTML code using the Graph API?  Using Firebug extension for Firefox, I can see the html code, but I can't access it through R.  I'm not interested in specific data like likes, or posts, just the html code. Any suggestions on how I can access the html code for a facebook page?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Might be better to state what you're trying to get from the page(s) rather than what you're currently trying. I think you almost assuredly want to use the Graph API, but it depends on what you're aiming for.

Comment: Thanks, after reading up on the Graph API, this looks like the way to go, since trying at to access the webpage without tell R/Facebook to log you in only give you a redirect page to the login.  Thanks though!

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
txt <- getURLContent("https://www.facebook.com/nytimes/", ssl.verifypeer = FALSE, followlocation = TRUE)
```

`getURL` may also work with `followlocation = TRUE`. It worked on my linux box but not on a windows machine.

Comment: This did return more than an empty string, but only the html for the default login in page (as far as I could tell).  Looks like the Graph API is the way to go.  Have you had luck accessed the Graph API through R?

Comment: Yes that is what you asked for.